# Balsamiq Mockups Wireframes icon is missing

Tags: bug, support, status-completed, mockups

I tried to edit the mockup on an existing ux.stackexchange post, but when trying, only got a big empty white popup.

For testing, I then started to create a new post, but the icon to lunch the mockup editor was missing.  I am able to click the location where it normally is and it appeared to open, but just got the big empty white popup again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that https://ux.stackexchange.com/content/balsamiq/mockups-web.swf is 404. Friends at StackExchange, let us know if you need any assitance fixing this. Maybe it's time to update the integration? We've come a long way since the version you have today. Email me at peldi@balsamiq.com if you'd like to chat!

Answer (score 1):

Whoops!

We moved our content directories around, but looks like we forgot to reference the button image (and the balsamic swf reference) to use the new location!

Fixed and will be with you in the next build.

Sorry about that.